# Am i right with the assumption that basically every time we see "NAT" being used for SOHO environments, its actually PAT?

Tags: networking, nat

I am just a bit confused because on the one hand i thought that i have good knowledge and that what we know as NAT is mostly PAT. On the other hand, i see the term NAT being used for the same scenarios even from "official" sources - for example some online services / games have settings for NAT strictness (MW2 for example) - wouldnt developers know about that mistake, if it would be one?

Comment: To expand on @Ramhound's answer below, NAT strictness type [simplistically] refers to port redirects [port forwarding].  Often, even though it's a really bad idea since it's insecure and a massive security concern that's actively exploited, many rely on UPnP on the WAN facing router instead of taking the handful of minutes it takes to configure individual port forwarding rules within the router's firewall.  NAT strictness type Open should never be strived for, as it essentially means the router's firewall is being completely bypassed for traffic to that specific downstream device.

Answer (score 0):

> I am just a bit confused because on the one hand i thought that i have good knowledge and that what we know as NAT is mostly PAT.

While PAT might be an extension of NAT is most certainly is not NAT.  NAT deals with mapping a public IP address to a single private IP address.  While PAT is mapping a single public IP address to multiple private IP addresses.

What you might be thinking of is Carrier-grade NAT (CGNAT), but in the case of CGNAT, you are not linking a single public IP address to multiple IP Addresses.  What actually is happening is you are never assigning a public IP Address to the consumer (client) device, but are assigning a private IP Address to the (client) device, and linking that private IP address to any number of public IP addresses you own.

> On the other hand, i see the term NAT being used for the same scenarios even from "official" sources - for example some online services / games have settings for NAT strictness (MW2 for example) - wouldnt developers know about that mistake, if it would be one?

NAT strictness (Open, Moderate, Strict) is simply a concept to determine if one client can communicate with another client.  These developers are absolutely not using PAT and NAT interchangeably.  **PAT, NAT, and CGNAT are absolutely different and unique to one another.**